# Radio button validation alert not showing - works on everything else

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a cfmail form for a nonprofit to allow potential vendors to request a spot at the next fundraiser. All fields are required but the radio buttons are not showing the validation alert if not selected.

EDIT:
I need the user to check either Yes or No when asked "Will vendor be selling at the event?" If the user checks "Yes", we'll display additional fields (State Tax ID and a textarea asking for more details on their product) that will be REQUIRED. If the user selects "NO" the TaxID and Details will NOT be required but we will be eventually be adding questions as to if they're a 501c3 or not.

I'm javascript illiterate so I had someone else write the JS but she had to move on to other obligations before getting the radio buttons working and I need this working before she'll have time to get back to it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the Code:

```js
// phone number

function phoneFormat(input) { //returns (###) ###-####
  input = input.replace(/\D/g, '');
  var size = input.length;
  if (size > 0) {
    input = "(" + input
  }
  if (size > 3) {
    input = input.slice(0, 4) + ") " + input.slice(4, 11)
  }
  if (size > 6) {
    input = input.slice(0, 9) + "-" + input.slice(9)
  }
  return input;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitall").click(function() {

    if (oked) {
      $('#submitall').prop('disabled', true);
      $("#submitall").html("Sending...");
      $("#submitall").submit();

    }
  });

  $('#salesyes').click(function() {
    if ($('#salesyes').is(':checked')) {
      $("#statesales").css("display", "block");
      $("#StateTaxNumber").prop('required', true);
      $("#Details").prop('required', true);
    } else {
      $("#statesales").css("display", "none");
      $("#StateTaxNumber").prop('required', false);
      $("#Details").prop('required', false);
    }
  });
  $('#salesno').click(function() {
    if ($('#salesno').is(':checked')) {
      $("#statesales").css("display", "none");
      $("#StateTaxNumber").prop('required', false);
      $("#Details").prop('required', false);
    } else {
      $("#statesales").css("display", "block");
      $("#StateTaxNumber").prop('required', true);
      $("#Details").prop('required', true);
    }
  });

});

function countChecked() {
  //$("#validateSend").bind('change', function()  {
  console.log("validateSend clicked");

  var cBox = $("#validateSend");
  console.log(cBox);

  console.log(cBox.prop('checked'));

  if (cBox.prop('checked')) {

    $('#submitall').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('#submitall').prop('disabled', true);
  }
}; //end countchecked

// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {


    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {

      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {


        if (form.checkValidity() === false || $('input[name="Sales"]:checked').length == 0) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- vendor app -->
<div class="container mt-2">
  <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 Sponsors text-center">
      <form class="needs-validation" action="/Vendors/index.cfm" id="Vendors" method="post" novalidate>
        <input type="hidden" name="Vendors_submit" value="yes">
        <!-- company name -->
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="Company" class="form-label text-right">Business/Organization:<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
          <input id="Company" name="Company" placeholder="Business/Organization Name" type="text" class="form-control" style="text-transform: capitalize;" required>
          <div class="valid-feedback">
            Looks good!
          </div>
          <div class="invalid-feedback text-left">
            Please enter the name of the company or individual interested in the Vendor spot.
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- phone -->
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="Phone" class="form-label text-right">Phone:<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
          <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="(555) 555-5555" class="form-control input-md" onInput="this.value = phoneFormat(this.value)" />
          <div class="valid-feedback">
            Looks good!
          </div>
          <div class="invalid-feedback text-left">
            Please enter your phone number.
          </div>
        </div>
       
        <!-- is vendor selling? -->
        <div class="form-group row mt-5">
          <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <strong>Will vendor be selling at the event?<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></strong>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-12 text-center my-auto">
            <input class="align-left" type="radio" name="Sales" id="salesyes" value="Yes" required> Yes
            <input class="align-left ml-5" type="radio" name="Sales" id="salesno" value="No"> No
          </div>
          <div class="valid-feedback">
            Looks good!
          </div>
          <div class="invalid-feedback text-center">
            Please select Yes or No.
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- State Sales Tax certificate -->
        <div id="statesales" style="display:none">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-12 text-left font-italic text-danger mb-4">
              Some notice stuff here.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="StateTaxNumber" class="form-label text-left">State Sales Tax Number:<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
            <input id="StateTaxNumber" name="StateTaxNumber" placeholder="State Sales Tax Number if applicable" type="text" class="form-control">
            <div class="valid-feedback">
              Looks good!
            </div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback text-left">
              Please enter State sales tax number.
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- details -->
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="Details" class="form-label">Please describe product or service for sale:<sup class="text-danger">*</sup></label>
            <textarea id="Details" name="Details" cols="40" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
            <div class="valid-feedback">
              Looks good!
            </div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback text-left">
              Please enter your details.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--./end display-none -->

        
        
        
        <!-- agree to regulations / restrictions -->
        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-10 text-center my-auto text-danger">
            <input type="checkbox" name="validateSend" id="validateSend" value="1" onclick="countChecked();" /><sup class="text-danger">*</sup>
            <i>I have read and understand all the Park's rules and regulations as well as the Requirements and Restrictions listed above.<sup class="text-danger">*</sup>
                                    <div class="valid-feedback">
                                        Looks good!
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback text-left">
                                        Please enter your details.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <button name="submitall" id="submitall" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger  mt-4 ml-2 text-center" disabled="disabled">Send Request</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It is not recommended to just dump code together and hoping it works and when it doesn't ask here... Can you remove all irrelevant and working code from your script, then perhaps we can see the problem

Comment: I gave it a try... not sure if I did it correctly.

Comment: I don't get it, the radio buttons always have an option selected in your example. This is pretty much the point of using radio buttons. Checking their validity for being required is therefor useless. Maybe add to your question what exactly you are expecting. What is happening now, and what you would like to happen.

Comment: I chose NOT to set one as selected because, based on the user selection,  I want to display additional options. e.g. If user selects "Yes" we'll display fields requiring State Tax ID and a list of items being sold.

Comment: Edited question to better explain what I'm looking to achieve.